# Requesting user´s digital certificate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5, digital-certificate

I have a digital certificate but it´s is an card, so I don´t have access to my private key. I am developing an app that I want the user to have an option to log in using its certificate.

I want my application to request user´s certificate.

How do I have to procced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Request.ClientCertificate.Subject;
```

Does the job! ;O)